# How to see to whom did I send code for code review in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I have created a shelveset and send it for code review. Is there any way to verify if the code review request has actually reached the reviewer? When I go to TFS >> My Work >> My Code reviews, I can only see the last review request. How to see all the review requests I have sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Reviews get stored as work items.

You could use work item query to track this. Create a custom "Query" with filter

```
Work Item Type = Code Review Request
```

And actually in Visual Studio--**My work**, you could see the user name you have sent to:

[image]

*77* is the work item ID for code review, *114551749* is the name of reviewer.

Open the code review work item you could also find the information you need,

[image]

There should be a child work item linked for a reviewer, assigned to should be whom you sent code.

Comment: Thanks, that did work. I had to add one more filter in query to see my requests ( `Created By = <user name>`